# How Eclipse Plugin can programmatically pass Java VM Arguments

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jvm-arguments

I'm programming an Eclipse Plugin which is actually a profiler that instruments the code using a Java Agent jar file.

I have programmed a custom **Launch Configuration** and also defined the **Launch Configuration Tab Group** for that. They are working fine and running local Java Projects. I want my plugin to automatically pass Java Agent jar file in vm arguments of **JavaArgumentsTab** so that code can be instrumented.

My Launch Configuration Code

```
public class MyJavaDelegate extends JavaLaunchDelegate
{
    @Override
    public void launch(ILaunchConfiguration configuration, String mode, ILaunch launch, IProgressMonitor monitor)
            throws CoreException
    {
        super.launch(configuration, mode, launch, monitor);
        System.out.println("Custom Lanucher Launched");
    }
}
```

My Launch Configuration Tab Group Code

```
public class MyJavaTabGroup extends AbstractLaunchConfigurationTabGroup
{

    JavaMainTab jmTab;
    JavaArgumentsTab jaTab;
    JavaJRETab jjTab;
    CommonTab cTab;

    @Override
    public void createTabs(ILaunchConfigurationDialog dialog, String mode)
    {
        jmTab = new JavaMainTab();
        jaTab = new JavaArgumentsTab();
        jjTab = new JavaJRETab();
        cTab = new CommonTab();

        setTabs(new ILaunchConfigurationTab[] { jmTab , jaTab, jjTab, cTab });      
    }

}
```

As JavaArgumentsTab takes the vm arguments, I'm trying to set vm arguments by code but I don't find any method of JavaArgumentsTab class that allow me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is create your own subclass of [`JavaArgumentsTab`](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/debug/ui/launchConfigurations/JavaArgumentsTab.html) and override [`setDefaults`](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/debug/ui/ILaunchConfigurationTab.html?is-external=true#setDefaults-org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy-).

`setDefaults` javadoc is:

> Initializes the given launch configuration with default values for
>   this tab. This method is called when a new launch configuration is
>   created such that the configuration can be initialized with meaningful
>   values. This method may be called before this tab's control is
>   created.

For e.g.:

```java
import org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy;
import org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaArgumentsTab;
import org.eclipse.jdt.launching.IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants;

public class CustomJavaArgumentsTab extends JavaArgumentsTab {

    @Override
    public void setDefaults(ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy config) {
        // start with the normal defaults for this tab...
        super.setDefaults(config);
        // ... then set/override them with what I want
        // ATTR_VM_ARGUMENTS is defaulted to null, provide my desired default
        config.setAttribute(IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants.ATTR_VM_ARGUMENTS, "my desired default");
    }
}
```

As you can see from this screenshot, "my desired default" appears in my launch configuration by default:

[image: vmargs]